# How to convert a list of sf spatial points into a routable graph

Tags: r, graph, dodgr

I have an `sf dataframe` object with a series of points representing the shape of a bus route. I would like to turn this object into a routable graph so I can estimate the time it takes to traverse  from point `c` to `t`.

Here is what I've tried using the `dodgr` [package](https://github.com/ATFutures/dodgr) but I am not sure what I'm doing wrong here:

```
library(dodgr)
graph <- weight_streetnet(mydata, wt_profile = "motorcar", type_col="highway" , id_col = "id")
```

> Error in check_highway_osmid(x, wt_profile) : 
>     Please specify type_col to be used for weighting streetnet

### Reproducible data

The data looks like in the image below

```
mydata <- structure(list(shape_id = c(52421L, 52421L, 52421L, 52421L, 52421L, 
                              52421L, 52421L, 52421L, 52421L, 52421L, 52421L, 52421L, 52421L, 
                              52421L, 52421L, 52421L, 52421L, 52421L, 52421L, 52421L), length = structure(c(0.191422504106197, 
                              0.191422504106197, 0.191422504106197, 0.191422504106197, 0.191422504106197, 
                              0.191422504106197, 0.191422504106197, 0.191422504106197, 0.191422504106197, 
                              0.191422504106197, 0.191422504106197, 0.191422504106197, 0.191422504106197, 
                              0.191422504106197, 0.191422504106197, 0.191422504106197, 0.191422504106197, 
                              0.191422504106197, 0.191422504106197, 0.191422504106197), units = structure(list(
                              numerator = "km", denominator = character(0)), class = "symbolic_units"), class = "units"), 
                              geometry = structure(list(structure(c(-46.5623281998182, 
                              -23.5213458001468), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-46.562221, 
                              -23.52129), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-46.562121, 
                              -23.521235), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-46.5620233332577, 
                              -23.5211840000609), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-46.561925666591, 
                              -23.5211330000609), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-46.561828, 
                              -23.521082), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-46.5618098335317, 
                              -23.5212126666783), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-46.5617916670273, 
                              -23.5213433333544), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-46.5617735004869, 
                              -23.5214740000284), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-46.5617553339104, 
                              -23.5216046667004), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-46.5617371672978, 
                              -23.5217353333702), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-46.5617190006492, 
                              -23.5218660000379), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-46.5617008339645, 
                              -23.5219966667036), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-46.5616826672438, 
                              -23.5221273333671), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-46.5616645004869, 
                              -23.5222580000284), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-46.5616463336941, 
                              -23.5223886666877), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-46.5616281668651, 
                              -23.5225193333449), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-46.56161, 
                              -23.52265), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-46.5617355000207, 
                              -23.5226427501509), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-46.5618610000276, 
                              -23.5226355002012), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg"))), class = c("sfc_POINT", 
                              "sfc"), precision = 0, bbox = structure(c(xmin = -46.5623281998182, 
                              ymin = -23.52265, xmax = -46.56161, ymax = -23.521082), class = "bbox"), crs = structure(list(
                              epsg = 4326L, proj4string = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"), class = "crs"), n_empty = 0L), 
                              id = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", 
                              "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t"), speed_kmh = c(11, 
                              11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 
                              11, 11, 11, 11)), sf_column = "geometry", agr = structure(c(shape_id = NA_integer_, 
                              length = NA_integer_, id = NA_integer_, speed_kmh = NA_integer_
                              ), class = "factor", .Label = c("constant", "aggregate", "identity"
                              )), row.names = c("1.13", "1.14", "1.15", "1.16", "1.17", "1.18", 
                              "1.19", "1.20", "1.21", "1.22", "1.23", "1.24", "1.25", "1.26", 
                              "1.27", "1.28", "1.29", "1.30", "1.31", "1.32"), class = c("sf", 
                              "data.table", "data.frame"))
```

[image]

Comment: Just a comment: minimal example code makes life easier for developers. Interesting problem though, look forward to seeing and thinking about solutions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `weight_streetnet` function is really only designed to handle actual street networks, generally as produced by the `osmdata::osmdata_sf/sp/sc()` functions. It can nevertheless be tweaked to handle cases like this. The main thing needed is to convert the points into something that knows about edges in between them, like an `sf::LINESTRING` object:

```
x <- sf::st_combine (mydata) %>%
    sf::st_cast ("LINESTRING") %>%
    sf::st_sf ()
```

That gives a single-row object which can then be converted to `dodgr` format, and the `id` values matched back on to the edges

```
net <- weight_streetnet (x, type_col = "shape_id", id_col = "id", wt_profile = 1)
net$from_id <- mydata$id [as.integer (net$from_id)]
net$to_id <- mydata$id [as.integer (net$to_id)]
```

At that point, `dodgr` will have calculated and inserted the distances directly from the geographic coordinates. Your distances can then also be inserted and used for routing by replacing the `d_weighted` values:

```
net$d_weighted <- as.numeric (mydata$length [1])
dodgr_dists (net, from = "c", to = "t") # 236.0481
```

If you really want your distances to represent absolute distances used to calculate the final result, then simply replace the `$d` values

```
net$d <- net$d_weighted
dodgr_dists (net, from = "c", to = "t") # 3.254183
```

Note that for "simple" problems like this, `igraph` will generally be faster, because it calculates routes using a single set of weights. The only real advantage of `dodgr` in this context is the ability to use "dual weights" - the `$d_weighted` and `$d` values - such that the route is calculated according to `$d_weighted`, and the final distances according to `$d`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to include this in a 'tidy' workflow, you could also consider using a mix between `sf` and `tidygraph`. The latter offers a tidy framework for networks/graphs, in the form of a `tbl_graph` class, which subclasses `igraph` (hence, you can use `tbl_graph` objects inside all `igraph` functions as being an `igraph` object). However, you can analyze your nodes and edges as being tibbles, and use functions as `filter()`, `select()`, `mutate()`, et cetera. Of course, these tibbles can also contain a geometry list column that we know from `sf`, adding geographic information to the nodes and edges.

The approach is far from perfect yet, and improvements would be very welcome, but still, it shows another way of handling the problem.

```r
# Load libraries.
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
library(tidygraph)
library(igraph)
library(units)
```

Just as in the other answers, we need to create edges between the nodes. For now, I assume that the points are simply connected in alphabetical order. For the `tidygraph` approach, however, we seem to need numeric ID's rather than characters.

```r
# Add a numeric ID column to the nodes.
nodes <- mydata %>%
    rename(id_chr = id) %>%
    rowid_to_column("id") %>%
    select(id, id_chr, everything())

# Define the source node of each edge, and the target node of each edge.
sources <- nodes %>% slice(-n())
targets <- nodes %>% slice(-1)

# Write a function to create lines between data frames of source and target points.
pt2l <- function(x, y) { st_linestring(rbind(st_coordinates(x), st_coordinates(y))) }

# Create the edges.
edges <- tibble(
        from = sources %>% pull(id), 
        to = targets %>% pull(id), 
        length = sources %>% pull(length), 
        speed = sources %>% pull(speed_kmh),
        geometry = map2(st_geometry(sources), st_geometry(targets), pt2l)
    ) %>% st_as_sf() %>% st_set_crs(st_crs(nodes))

# Add a time column to the edges.
edges <- edges %>%
    mutate(speed = set_units(speed, "km/h")) %>%
    mutate(time = length / speed)

# Clean up the nodes data.
nodes <- nodes %>%
    select(-length, -speed_kmh)

# Create the tbl_graph object out of the nodes and edges.
# Providing the edges as sf object is problematic for tidygraph, unfortunately.
# Therefore, we have to provide them as a tibble.
graph <- tbl_graph(nodes = nodes, edges = as_tibble(edges), directed = FALSE)
```

This gives us the following `tbl_graph` object:

```
# A tbl_graph: 20 nodes and 19 edges
#
# An undirected simple graph with 1 component
#
# Node Data: 20 x 4 (active)
     id id_chr shape_id              geometry
  <int> <chr>     <int>           <POINT [°]>
1     1 a         52421 (-46.56233 -23.52135)
2     2 b         52421 (-46.56222 -23.52129)
3     3 c         52421 (-46.56212 -23.52124)
4     4 d         52421 (-46.56202 -23.52118)
5     5 e         52421 (-46.56193 -23.52113)
6     6 f         52421 (-46.56183 -23.52108)
# … with 14 more rows
#
# Edge Data: 19 x 6
   from    to    length   speed                               geometry      time
  <int> <int>      [km]  [km/h]                       <LINESTRING [°]>       [h]
1     1     2 0.1914225      11 (-46.56233 -23.52135, -46.56222 -23.5… 0.017402…
2     2     3 0.1914225      11 (-46.56222 -23.52129, -46.56212 -23.5… 0.017402…
3     3     4 0.1914225      11 (-46.56212 -23.52124, -46.56202 -23.5… 0.017402…
# … with 16 more rows
```

Now we have everything in a graph structure, we can select the node we want to route from, and the node we want to route to, and find the shortest path between them with the travel time as weight variable, using the `shortest_path` function from `igraph`. We now just work with a one-to-one route ('c' to 't'), but it would be just the same for one-to-many, many-to-one or many-to-many.

```r
# Select the node from which and to which the shortest path should be found.
from_node <- graph %>%
  activate(nodes) %>%
  filter(id_chr == "c") %>%
  pull(id)

to_node <- graph %>%
  activate(nodes) %>%
  filter(id_chr == "t") %>%
  pull(id)

# Find the shortest path between these nodes
path <- shortest_paths(
  graph = graph,
  from = from_node,
  to = to_node,
  output = 'both',
  weights = graph %>% activate(edges) %>% pull(time)
)
```

The resulting path is a list with the nodes and edges that make up the path.

```
$vpath
$vpath[[1]]
+ 18/20 vertices, from e43a089:
 [1]  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20


$epath
$epath[[1]]
+ 17/19 edges from e43a089:
 [1]  3-- 4  4-- 5  5-- 6  6-- 7  7-- 8  8-- 9  9--10 10--11 11--12 12--13
[11] 13--14 14--15 15--16 16--17 17--18 18--19 19--20
```

We can create a subgraph of the original graph that only contains the nodes and edges of the shortest path.

```r
path_graph <- graph %>%
    subgraph.edges(eids = path$epath %>% unlist()) %>%
    as_tbl_graph()
```

```
# A tbl_graph: 18 nodes and 17 edges
#
# An undirected simple graph with 1 component
#
# Node Data: 18 x 4 (active)
     id id_chr shape_id              geometry
  <int> <chr>     <int>           <POINT [°]>
1     3 c         52421 (-46.56212 -23.52124)
2     4 d         52421 (-46.56202 -23.52118)
3     5 e         52421 (-46.56193 -23.52113)
4     6 f         52421 (-46.56183 -23.52108)
5     7 g         52421 (-46.56181 -23.52121)
6     8 h         52421 (-46.56179 -23.52134)
# … with 12 more rows
#
# Edge Data: 17 x 6
   from    to    length   speed                               geometry      time
  <int> <int>      [km]  [km/h]                       <LINESTRING [°]>       [h]
1     1     2 0.1914225      11 (-46.56212 -23.52124, -46.56202 -23.5… 0.017402…
2     2     3 0.1914225      11 (-46.56202 -23.52118, -46.56193 -23.5… 0.017402…
3     3     4 0.1914225      11 (-46.56193 -23.52113, -46.56183 -23.5… 0.017402…
# … with 14 more rows
```

Here, something happens which I don't like. Tidygraph/igraph seems to have an internal node ID structure, and you see that in the subgraph, the `from` and `to` columns in the egdes data don't match with our `id` column in the nodes data anymore, but instead simply refer to the row numbers of the nodes data. I am not sure how to fix that.

Either way, we now have our path from 'c' to 't' as a subgraph, and can easily analyze it. For example, by calculating the total travel time of the path (as was the question).

```
path_graph %>%
    activate(edges) %>%
    as_tibble() %>%
    summarise(total_time = sum(time))
```

```
# A tibble: 1 x 1
  total_time
         [h]
1  0.2958348
```

But it is also easy to plot it, with geographic information preserved (just by exporting nodes and edges as sf objects).

```
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = graph %>% activate(edges) %>% as_tibble() %>% st_as_sf(), col = 'darkgrey') +
  geom_sf(data = graph %>% activate(nodes) %>% as_tibble() %>% st_as_sf(), col = 'darkgrey', size = 0.5) +
  geom_sf(data = path_graph %>% activate(edges) %>% as_tibble() %>% st_as_sf(), lwd = 1, col = 'firebrick') +
  geom_sf(data = path_graph %>% activate(nodes) %>% filter(id %in% c(from_node, to_node)) %>% as_tibble() %>% st_as_sf(), size = 2)
```

[plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJUlV.png)

An r-spatial blog post might be coming up on this tidygraph-sf approach ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can solve it by transforming your data into an *igraph* object and use the functionalities in the *igraph* library. 
You need to establish the **Edges** and **Vertex** as well as **weight** values.
In *igraph* an Edge is a link representing a connection among two nodes (Source and Target). In this case, a link is a *"street"* and the points are the nodes.

```
library(igraph)
GraphResult <- data.frame(Source = c(NULL), 
                      Target = c(NULL), 
                      weight  = c(NULL))

for (i in 1:(dim(mydata)[1] - 1)) {

  TempGraphResult <- data.frame(Source = c(0), 
                                Target = c(0), 
                                weight  = c(0))

  TempGraphResult$Source[1] <- mydata$id[i]
  TempGraphResult$Target[1] <- mydata$id[i + 1]
  TempGraphResult$weight[1] <- mydata$length[i]

  GraphResult <- rbind(GraphResult, TempGraphResult) }

MyIgraph <- graph_from_data_frame(GraphResult) 

#In this case works perfectly. But if you have more weight variables and even
#additional variables for the nodes, igraph have functions for constructing the
#igraph object

distances(MyIgraph, "c", "t") #returns 3.254183. Seems correct (0.1914225*17)
SquareMatrix <- distances(MyIgraph)

#*distances() is a function from igraph that performs the routing calculations.
```

Is possible to achieve more complex networks and calculate routes.  For example, you can set the direction of the roads.

Maybe dodger can handle the problem, but I am not sure.

Comment: This is very helpful, @Orlando. Thanks again!

Comment: I have a particular interest in the topic. More precisely in how to use R to calculate travel times and routes for different formats. For example, it would be useful to make computations using lines in .shp formats (with no relation to OSM). But it should be something *"easy"* to do and with a lot of flexibility; this is needed for many transport problems and in many transport analysis agencies. I see something like the *Network Analyst*  of ARCGIS being developed for R in the near future. Maybe Dodger is in that path. Please let me know when you get to a more robust answer to your problem.